# Update in JPA without native query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have an entity class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table("invite_data")
public class InvitationData {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "rl_id" )
private Long id;

@Column( name = "rl_invitee_email" )
private String inviteeEmailId;

@Column( name = "rl_generated_link" )
private String generatedLink;

@Column( name = "rl_expire_at" )
private Calendar expiresAt;

@Column( name = "rl_generated_code" )
private String generatedCode;

@Column( name = "rl_created_at" )
private Calendar invitedAt;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "rl_frn_created_by", referencedColumnName = "u_id" )
private UserModel invitedBy;

@Column( name = "rl_is_active" )
private Boolean isActive;

@Column( name = "rl_is_used" )
private Boolean isUsed;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "rl_frn_invited_role", referencedColumnName = "as_id" )
private AccountStatus invitedRole;
}
```

I am unable to perform update queries.

```
public interface InvitationRepository extends JpaRepository<InvitationData, Long> {

@Modifying( clearAutomatically = true )
@Query( "UPDATE InvitationData invite SET invite.isActive = false WHERE invite.id= :invitationId AND invite.isUsed = false AND"
        + " invite.isActive = true AND invite.expiresAt >=:now AND i.invitedBy =:user" )
Integer cancelInvitation( @Param( "invitationId" ) Long id, @Param( "now" ) Calendar now,
        @Param( "user" ) UserModel user );
```

}

The application fails to start/boot with the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **Invalid path:** 
'i.invitedBy' [UPDATE com.highpeak.tlp.datastore.model.InvitationData 
invite SET invite.isActive = false WHERE invite.id= :invitationId AND 
invite.isUsed = false AND invite.isActive = true AND invite.expiresAt 
>=:now AND i.invitedBy =:user]

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
**Invalid path:** 'i.invitedBy' [UPDATE 
com.highpeak.tlp.datastore.model.InvitationData invite SET 
invite.isActive = false WHERE invite.id= :invitationId AND 
invite.isUsed = false AND invite.isActive = true AND invite.expiresAt 
>=:now AND i.invitedBy =:user]
```

What might be the issue? If I have a foreign key in my Entity class, can I directly pass the Entity class as argument, or should I perform a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not correct.

This

```
i.invitedBy =:user
```

has to be

```
invite.invitedBy =:user
```

Comment: Can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Thanks for the help. Sorry for posting question without validating properly